# Is it bad to use numpy arrays in this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

**Main Question:**
Is it bad (perhaps in terms of computation time or memory) to using `np.array([[1, 2, 3]])` everywhere instead of `np.array([1, 2, 3])`?

**Motivation:**

I come form a math background, so I like to think of things in terms of vectors and matrices. For example, I think of `y = np.array([1, 2, 3])` as a row vector, or as a 1 X 3 matrix. However, numpy doesn't treat y quite like a 1 X 3 matrix. For instance, if we take a 2 X 3 matrix `A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])` numpy will allow us to do the matrix multiplication`A @ y` even though the dimensions are (2 X 3) times (1 X 3) don't make sense mathematically.

On the other hand, `y @ A.T` gives an error even though the dimensions (1 X 3) times (3 X 2) make sense.

So in conclusion `np.array([1, 2, 3])` does not behave exactly as a matrix. However, from my experiments it seems that numpy does treat `np.array([[1, 2, 3]])` as a bona fide 1 X 3 matrix. So if there are no downsides, I would prefer to use this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` has an old subclass `np.matrix` that makes sure everything has exactly 2 dimensions.  But it is no longer recommended.

`numpy` tries to work equally well with 0,1,2, and more dimensions.

```
In [69]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
In [70]: x = np.array([1,2,3])
In [71]: y = np.array([[1,2,3]])
In [72]: A.shape
Out[72]: (2, 3)
```

Matrix product of a (2,3) with (3,) resulting a (2,).  It's docs say it expands the (3,) to (3,1), getting a (2,1) result, and then squeezing out that 1:

```
In [73]: A@x
Out[73]: array([14, 32])
```

The (2,3) with (1,3) transposed produces (2,1):

```
In [74]: A@y.T
Out[74]: 
array([[14],
       [32]])
```

(3,) with (3,2) => (2,):

```
In [78]: x@A.T
Out[78]: array([14, 32])
```

(1,3) with (3,2) => (1,3):

```
In [79]: y@A.T
Out[79]: array([[14, 32]])
```

How does your math intuition handle 3d or higher arrays?  `matmul/@` handles them nicely.  `np.einsum` does even better.

---

While you can create a (1,n) arrays, if it makes you more comfortable.  But beware that you'll still end up with 1 or even 0d results.

For example with indexing:

```
In [80]: A
Out[80]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [81]: A[1,:]
Out[81]: array([4, 5, 6])
In [82]: A[:,1]
Out[82]: array([2, 5])
In [83]: A[1,1]
Out[83]: 5
In [84]: A[1,1].shape
Out[84]: ()
In [85]: A[1,1].ndim
Out[85]: 0
```

or reduction along an axis:

```
In [86]: A.sum(axis=1)
Out[86]: array([ 6, 15])
```

though it's possible to retain dimensions:

```
In [87]: A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[87]: 
array([[ 6],
       [15]])
In [88]: A[[1],:]
Out[88]: array([[4, 5, 6]])
In [89]: A[:,[1]]
Out[89]: 
array([[2],
       [5]])
```

Another to keep in mind is that numpy operators most operation element-wise.  The main exception being `@`.  Where as in MATLAB `A*B` is matrix multiplication, and `A.*B` is element-wise.  Add to that `broadcasting`, which allows us to add a (2,3) and (3,) array:

```
In [90]: A+x
Out[90]: 
array([[2, 4, 6],
       [5, 7, 9]])
```

Here (2,3) + (3,) => (2,3) + (1,3) => (2,3).  The (3,) 1d array often behaves as a (1,3) or even (1,1,3) if needed.  But expansion in the other direction has to be explicit.

```
In [92]: A / A.sum(axis=1)          # (2,3) with (2,) error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-92-fec3395556f9>", line 1, in <module>
    A / A.sum(axis=1)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,) 

In [93]: A / A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)   # (2,3) with (2,1) ok
Out[93]: 
array([[0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       ],
       [0.26666667, 0.33333333, 0.4       ]])
In [94]: A / A.sum(axis=1)[:,None]
Out[94]: 
array([[0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       ],
       [0.26666667, 0.33333333, 0.4       ]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The concept of a zero - dimensional array seems strange to me; I would expect such an array to be completely empty, or at most an unordered list. But somehow it's a 1 X 3 matrix, even though it's not actually a 1 X 3 matrix. What is the advantage of using 0-dimensional arrays over 1-dimensional ones?

Comment: A 0d array has 1 element; it is roughly equivalent to a scalar.  But MATLAB doesn't have scalars; the closest is a (1,1) shape matrix.  I added some examples of how 2 (or higher dimensional) arrays may drop in dimension.

Comment: Thank you so much for the examples. Ah okay I like the analogy with scalars. Just to clarify np.array([1, 2, 3]) is a 0-dimensional array, right?

Comment: No that is 1d shape (3,).  `np.array(4)` is 0d, shape () (empty tuple)

Comment: Ah okay so 0d really are like scalars. So there is something between 0d and 1d, and it is this (3, ) shape. Thanks

Comment: The dimension is the number of elements in the `shape` tuple.  `(3,)` is a 1 element tuple (review Python tuple basics if needed),  therefore the array is 1d.  `numpy` is used for a lot more than linear algebra (`@` is a relatively late addition as an operator).  It's the basis for `pandas` (tables and series), `scipy` (statistics, fft, integration, odes), and (now popular) 'machine learning'.